# Using ethtool with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager, netplan

I am new to using Ubuntu so appologies if some of the information is in complete or missing.

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on 2 systems which both have SPF ports, for some reason they are not auto negitating on thier own, but have found running teh command:

```
ethtool -s enp1s0f0 speed 1000 duplex full
```

enables the connection, however I am unable to find away of this command being run at boot, so that the connection can be enabled automatically.

Any help would be much appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own daemon with rc.local (local shell script):

vi /etc/rc.d/ethtool

```
#!/bin/sh -e
ethtool -s enp1s0f0 speed 1000 duplex full
exit 0
```

Make sure to save the file and make it executable (chmod +x)

Comment: Thank you, i ended up creating a service file to call the shell script, which contained the above information, which is working for me.